# inserting into database with foreign key constraints

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-administration

I am having trouble with the following issue:

I have two tables (for ex.)

```
 Table CARS:
 carID      |      Car Make
 1          |      Honda
 2          |      Misubishu
```

where carID is primary key

```
 Table MODELS
 modelID     |      mName       |      carID
 1           |      accord      |       1
```

where modelID is primary key and carID is foreign key (to CARS).

Now lets say that I want to insert Honda Civic into MODELS table.

I would insert civic and get the carID that matches Honda from the CARS table

I have been playing with INSERT SELECT statements, but I cannot get it to work; I have been doing something like this: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/46410/how-do-i-insert-a-row-which-contains-a-foreign-key

which seems to be exactly what I want but I still get sqlexceptions regarding f-key.

Thanks!

Comment: what was your query and what was the error message?

Comment: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails

was my error; I have tried a bunch of queries but my last one was :

Answer (score 1):

If modelID is auto_incremented you could do:

```
INSERT INTO models(mName,carID)
SELECT 'Civic',carID
FROM cars 
WHERE `Car Make` = 'Honda';
```

<kbd>[sqlfiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c2f451/1)</kbd>

If modelID is not auto_incremented, you would have to pass the id also.

Comment: Right idea.  The space in the car make field has to be escaped though.